# Rails Server command is failing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, failure, ruby

I´ve been trying to install rbenv, ruby and rails in my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ in the past couple of days and after some issues here and there I've managed to get everything installed with no errors

With rbenv I installed both Ruby 2.6.3 and Ruby 2.5.5
Using Rails 5.2.3

and with both ruby versions I am getting the same problem when I execute the command:

```
rails server
```

First the output shows this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/environment/hello_app $ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

And then the contents of the text file in the next link are shown.

Here is a link with the whole output:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjgo81zqeekfnvt/railsservererror.txt?dl=0

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know anything about Ruby. However, a) Does Ruby run any scripts at all? b) Is this an interpreter error, or a error with your code? c) Report this to Ruby's developers.

Comment: This is more a Rails problem, I haven´t been able to do any code. I am basically installing the Ruby on Rails framework, to be able to develop some web applications. But this seems to be happening only on the Raspberry Pi, that is why I am asking here because I would like to know if anyone else has ran into the same issue....

Comment: It could also be an issue with the Puma server that Rails tries to run when the command
```
rails server
```
 is executed...

Comment: Try to do a Hello World without running Puma, and see if that returns an issue.

Comment: You mean print "Hello World" to the console using Ruby?

Comment: Yes, this would tell you whether Puma is the issue or not.

Comment: Yes it Works

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> 2+2
=> 4
irb(main):002:0> print "Hello"
Hello=> nil
irb(main):003:0> print "Hello World"
Hello World=> nil
irb(main):004:0>

Comment: Ruby is not giving me any errors, the problem is when I try to start the Rails Server, which seems to be Puma

Comment: Ok, then we can proceed to fix Puma. Are you using the init.d documentation? If so, follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md)

Comment: But I want to be clear I have not modified or interacted with  Puma before, I just installed Rails and it comes with the Puma gems. I tried changing the version of Puma my application use to 3.12.1 and still get the same problem.
I am not sure about what to do next.

Comment: I issued this same problem on the puma GitHub section instead https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1797 . Maybe we should continue this discussion there